# elastic geo_distance_range on multiple points

Tags: json, elasticsearch

i am using elastic 1.5.

Let say that i has this query from elastic docomention:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance_range" : {
                "from" : "200km",
                "to" : "400km",
                "pin.location" : {
                    "lat" : 40,
                    "lon" : -70
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the bool query with should , it worked but its ugly solotion
I want make the query to return the documents in the range for few points and not just one.

Something like this :

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance_range" : {
                "from" : "200km",
                "to" : "400km",
                "pin.location" : {[
                    {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    } , 
                    {
                        "lat" : 56 ,
                        "lon" : -23
                    }
                ]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure it would work, but you could give it a try using the [OR operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-or-query.html), like this:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or" : [
                {"geo_distance_range" : {
                    "from" : "200km",
                    "to" : "400km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }}, 
                {"geo_distance_range" : {
                    "from" : "200km",
                    "to" : "400km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 56 , 
                        "lon" : -23
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is of any help.

Comment: unfortunately iam using elastic 1.5 . forgot to mention that it worked when i tried should from bool query. but its an ugly solotion.
Thanks!